# Eclemma: if statements in a method cover all possible inputs but eclemma flags the return statement at the end which will never be reached

Tags: java, junit, return, eclemma

I have a method which takes an array of integers as an input and outputs a string saying which type of triangle they form if the argument is of length 3 and outputting "invalid" otherwise.

```
    public class Triangle {
        public String typeOf(int[] args) {
            if (args.length < 3) return "invalid"; // invalid
            if (args[0] == args[1] && args[1] == args[2]) return "equilateral";
            if (args[0] == args[1] && args[0] != args[2]) return "isosceles";
            if  (args[0] == args[2] && args[0] != args[1]) return "isosceles";
            if  (args[1] == args[2] && args[0] != args[1]) return "isosceles";
            if (args[0] != args[1] && args[0] != args[2] && args[1] != args[2]) return "scalene";
            return "Error all the tests failed";
        }        
    }
```

The problem is that the final return statement "return "Error all the tests failed";" can't be reached as the previous if statements cover all possible inputs. This leads to Eclemma showing missing instructions but I can't take it out as I get an error saying it must return a result of type string. Is there a way to make Eclemma ignore this specific statement or a way to cover it in my tests? Tahnks

Answer (score 0):

Change your algorithm to have a single return statement, at the end. Then have each of the if-conditions set their result into the String that will get returned. If you are concerned about short-circuiting later checks once you know the answer, turn them into else if

For example:

```
public String typeOf(int[] args) {
  String result = "Error all the tests failed";
  if (args.length < 3) result = "invalid"; // invalid
  else if (args[0] == args[1] && args[1] == args[2]) result = "equilateral";
  // ..skipping a few..
  else result = "scalene";
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have all possible cases matching in the if condition and it never reach the final return statement.

Instead of having multiple return statement, you can do below

```
public String typeOf(int[] args) {
    String str = "isosceles";
    if (args.length < 3)
        str = "invalid"; // invalid
    else if (args[0] == args[1] && args[1] == args[2])
        str = "equilateral";
    else if (args[0] != args[1] && args[0] != args[2] && args[1] != args[2])
        str = "scalene";
    return str;
}
```